# RMI or Servlets to send objects to/from applet through firewalls?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, rmi, firewall

I have an approximately 8-year old system in which java applets communicate with a custom server (written in java) over a port using sockets. At any one time, there are no more than a a dozen or so users. More and more of our users are behind firewalls over which they have no control. The proposed solution is to find a way to send objects via port 80.

I'm leaning towards servlets. The major disadvantage is the time to learn how to put everything together (apache, tomcat, servlets).

However, RMI seems (on the face of it) more simple, but reading Oracle's FAQ about firewalls leads me to think it may not always work. Moreover, I've not seen a good guide on how it works with apache when they share a port.

Given the constraints: (1) must use java applets for clients, (2) have no control over clients' firewalls, (3) I'm a decent amateur programmer but not a professional and there aren't funds to hire a professional, which is the better route to go, or have a missed another solution?

Comment: When you say "Oracle's FAQ about firewalls", what document are you talking about?

Comment: see [download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html#firewall](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html#firewall)

Answer (score 2):

Given that it all currently works over RMI, i would lean towards [tunnelling RMI over HTTP](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch6.html). I've never done it, but it's an ancient feature of RMI that should work robustly.

You talk about sharing a port with Apache. You can't actually do this - only one process can listen on any given port. However, what you can do is sit Apache on port 80, and configure it to forward requests to RMI, which can listen on some other port. You can do this because (if i am reading this correctly!) baked into the guts of the RMI-over-HTTP method is the path `/cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi`. You can use Apache's famous [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) to catch requests to that path and pass them on to the Java process on its port. You can even put the RMI process on a completely different host, and pass requests to it over the network.